# My javascript code throw FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running the following code

```
var i = 0;
while (i != i + 1) {
    console.log(++i)
}
```

As per my understanding, I am only using one variable and therefore the program should never run out of memory(not for quite a while), but after few minutes, it throws the error.

Can anyone help me understand why it is behaving in this way

Comment: You have created an infinite loop

Comment: Performing a loop and logging to the console are not memory-consuming free operations.

Comment: Your `while` loop executes infinitely. Have you logically evaluated your code?. And when you log something onto your console, which requires some memory to store the value.

Comment: Why was this question heavily down voted? He was trying out a certain code, didn't understand it, posted it to ask why and he gets down voted. Like why?

Comment: it is not a infinite loop. it is supposed to go only till MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Comment: You are only doing 9007199254740991 `console.log` calls and it crashes?? Wow totally did not expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of the console are certainly kept somewhere, and that is growing all the time with your code. An infinitely (*) long text just does not fit into the memory, that is all.

Also, on top of that, `console.log()` may allocate multiple strings and ignite a regexp engine for every call. Garbage collection might not keep up with that. It is not a trivial function on the JavaScript side already: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/console/constructor.js#L214

> ```
> Console.prototype[kWriteToConsole] = function(streamSymbol, string) {
>   [...]
>
>   if (groupIndent.length !== 0) {
>     if (string.includes('\n')) {
>       string = string.replace(/\n/g, `\n${groupIndent}`);
>     }
>     string = groupIndent + string;
>   }
>   string += '\n';
>
>   if (ignoreErrors === false) return stream.write(string);
>
>   // and a similar one with extra steps for catching errors
>   [...]
> };
> ```

And there can be extra steps both on the stream-side and on the native part too.

---

(*) Ok, your text does not grow *infinitely*, but there will be <strike>2^52</strike> 2^53 calls, which is a bit more than 4.5 *peta*calls (peta=10^15, 1000000*giga). If each of them would consume just 1 bit, that would be far too much for your computer already.

Comment: so console keep the text in memory even after it has printed it on console?

Comment: @AbhishekAnand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026301/is-there-a-node-js-console-log-length-limit discusses that topic.

Comment: Just as a perfectionist sidenote: `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is 2^53 - 1. Fraction/Mantissa of float64 are 52 bits, but a leading 1 is assumed, and zero itself is covered differently.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to the console.log call. The garbage collection of the stream is not activated right away.
Running the following will not cause any issues with memory. Of course it will crash eventually because of the size of the number. But it will take a lot longer.

`var i = 0;
while (i != i + 1) {
    i++;
}`

More info about memory management with console.log: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1339

Comment: i was hoping that after a while i !=  i+1 will fail eventually after max safe integer

Comment: @AbhishekAnand `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is not a limit to number values, it's only the upper limit for accurate presentation of the integers.

Comment: after that i!==i+1 turns out to be false

Comment: @AbhishekAnand I don't know what you are thinking, but if the jitter (or related) doesnt optimize it away, even having an empty loop (no logging) until `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` will never ever complete. You vastly underestimate how large that number is.

Comment: i am not thinking anything, executing code till max_safe_integer does indeed stop. please do try to execute a code regarding that